# Why does my if statement ignore my conditions?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm programming a random event system that happens to users when logged in and I put the below piece of code into my include file.

```
$tehchance = mt_rand(1,15);
if ($tehchance == "1"){
$thewin = 10;
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET Points = Points + $thewin WHERE Handle = '$members[Handle]'");
}
```

I also have this for another event:

```
if ($tehchance == "2"){
$thekhwin = 5;
$thexpwin = 10;
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET Points = Points - $thekhwin WHERE Handle = '$members[Handle]'");
mysql_query("UPDATE members SET XP = XP + $thexpwin WHERE Handle = '$members[Handle]'");
}
```

The code will work but sometimes when $tehchance is equal to something else other than 1 or 2, it'll just ignore my conditions and update the members table without satisfying the if statement. From testing, it'll randomly add points or subtract points. I printed the random number from $tehchance and it still adds points even when it isn't equal to 1 or 2. Then sometimes it doesn't do anything to the members table. Really confused here.

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, you are comparing random generated integers to string values.

Comment: ...then there is likely something else amiss.

Comment: Add a debug echo inside of your conditional blocks, such as `if ($tehchance == 2) { echo 'it is 2'; /* rest of code... */ }`. More than likely, you modify `$tehchance` more than once, run your script more than once, or have an extraneous update elsewhere.

Comment: I've tried that, and I'm stumped. When $tehchance is equal to 1 or 2, it works just fine, but sometimes it'll add points or XP on a different number. I haven't modified $tehchance elsewhere and I changed "1" and "2" to 1 and 2. Same thing is happening.

Comment: Your code works fine at my side, can you provide some more code?

Comment: Well I do have two other if statements. `if($members['Handle']!=""){
if($members['Handle']=="Reaper"){` The first one just make sure the current visitor is logged in before even trying for a random event. The second one makes sure it only happens to me(for testing purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an if-then-else and debug that.

```
$tehchance = mt_rand(1,15);

if ($tehchance === 1){
    echo 'doing 1';
    $thewin = 10;
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET Points = Points + $thewin WHERE Handle = '$members[Handle]'");
} else if ($tehchance === 2){
    echo 'doing 2';
    $thekhwin = 5;
    $thexpwin = 10;
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET Points = Points - $thekhwin WHERE Handle = '$members[Handle]'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET XP = XP + $thexpwin WHERE Handle = '$members[Handle]'");
} else {
    echo 'doing nothing';
}
```

Comment: Okay after doing that, the members table STILL updates when it says doing nothing. Sometimes it'll do nothing like its supposed to, and then other times it will add points.

Comment: Sounds like you have the same code executing else where. It should not be outputting "doing nothing" and running the other if statements.

Comment: That's the thing, that's the only kind of code in my include. It's no where else. I have achievement functions that update to the members table, but they have nothing to do with adding points or XP. The changes that are happening are the Points and XP. Sometimes it'll randomly add 10 points when it says doing nothing. Sometimes it'll subtract 5 points and add 10 XP. It's like the if statements just work when they want to.

Comment: You will need to post more code in order to get additional help.

Answer (score 0):

because you are comparing to a string : "1" instead of the number 1 (without quotes)

Comment: While comparing a number would be better, PHP will coerce the values just fine. `1 == "1"` is true and `1 == "2"` is false. (These are easy cases though, there are some ... interesting conversion choices.)

Comment: I just changed it to a number without quotes and it still has the same behavior.

Comment: Is that a valid query? Points = Points + $points
Would you not have to do a 'select Points ' query first to get those values then do an UPDATE to put in the added values and not add them inline in your original UPDATE query?

Comment: Don't see why not, it's adding an amount to the existing amount.

Comment: I can try that but it works elsewhere on my site in that format. Let me give it a shot.

Comment: Still does the same thing. Updates whenever it wants to.